# 'No matching tab was found with the following properties: Title=Demo Web Shop*' when running testcase in Jenkins for a tosca testcase

Tags: jenkins, cicd, tosca

I have integrated Tosca with jenkins to run in local .The test runs successfully on jenkins .However I see below error in result.xml file .The tests run fine in Tosca its only in Jenkins that I see this error .What do I do?

This is the result.xml output

```
<testcase name="Shipping Costs" time="12.7" timestamp="2022-10-07T16:04:47.1086587+05:30" log="- Failed Shipping Costs {LogInfo='Execution will be continued with the next TestCase, because there was an error in the current TestCase.'} + Passed Open Web Shop - Failed Navigate to Log In Page {LogInfo='No matching tab was found with the following properties: Title=Demo Web Shop*'} ">
```

- Failed Shipping Costs {LogInfo='Execution will be continued with the next TestCase, because there was an error in the current TestCase.'} + Passed Open Web Shop - Failed Navigate to Log In Page {LogInfo='No matching tab was found with the following properties: Title=Demo Web Shop*'}

Comment: do you understand what this error message is telling you?

Comment: Not really @Psytho

Comment: A tab with opened page with title "Demo Web Shop*" was not found in your browser.

Comment: yeah that I do understand but then the same thing works on Tosca tool ....just that when i run through jenkins is when i encounter this error so i'm not able to understand why does it have trouble launching the application @Psytho

Comment: where di you get the file result.xml? is it from jenkins? I can't get the LogInfo message anywhere but in Tosca and i'd like to be able to get if from a report/file programmatically

Comment: is this issue still going for you? if not, what was the solution?
having a similar case here, and there it helped to open a 2nd tab in the browser which was then somehow recognized by tosca.
But never figured out why the first wasn't.